# How to put repetitive code from an object literal into a function and call with parameters?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have the following **object literal** being sent to an Ext JS Ext.FormPanel.

This form has a number of **form fields**, e.g. "Customer Contact", "Reason for Contact", etc.

Each of these need to be of type **dropdown** instead a simple **text field** as they are now.

I converted the **first field** to a dropdown:

```
var form_customer_contact = new Ext.FormPanel({
    frame:true,
    labelWidth: 110,
    labelAlign: 'right',
    bodyStyle:'padding:0',
    width: 300,
    height: 600,
    autoScroll: true,
    itemCls: 'form_row',
    defaultType: 'displayfield',
    items: [{
            fieldLabel: 'Customer Contact',
            name: 'customerContact',
            allowBlank:false,
            value: 'Mr. Smith'
        },{
            fieldLabel: 'Reason for Contact',
            width:          150,
            xtype:          'combo',
            mode:           'local',
            value:          '1',
            triggerAction:  'all',
            forceSelection: true,
            editable:       false,
            fieldLabel:     'Produkt',
            name:           'reason',
            hiddenName:     'reason',
            displayField:   'name',
            valueField:     'value',
            store:          new Ext.data.JsonStore({
                fields : ['name', 'value'],
                data   : [
                    {name : 'data correction',   value: '1'},
                    {name : 'new contact',  value: '2'},
                    {name : 'missing information', value: '3'}
                ]
            })
        }, {
            fieldLabel: 'Communication',
            name: 'communication',
            value: 'test'
        }, {
            fieldLabel: 'Related Order',
            name: 'relatedOrder',
            value: 'test'
        }, {
            fieldLabel: 'Date/Time',
            name: 'dateTime',
            value: 'test'
        }, {
            fieldLabel: 'Notes',
            name: 'notes',
            value: 'test'
        }
    ]
});
```

Now **all the other fields** need to be converted to a dropdown as well, but since about **80%** of the code will remain the same each, I want to simply call a **function**, e.g. like this:

```
getField('Reason for Contact', 'reason', {'data correction', 'new contact', 'missing information'})
getField('Communication', 'communication', {'telephone', 'fax', 'email'})
```

**What is the best way to create a function or object in Javascript which can be called as described above in order to reduce the code bloat in this example?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a factory function to do that like this:

```
var createCombo = function(label, name, values) {
    var i, data = [];

    for(i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        data.push({ name: values[i], value: i+1+'' });
    }   

    return new Ext.form.ComboBox({
        fieldLabel:     label,
        name:           name,
        width:          150,  
        mode:           'local',
        value:          '1',
        triggerAction:  'all',
        forceSelection: true,
        editable:       false,
        displayField:   'name',
        valueField:     'value',
        store:          new Ext.data.JsonStore({
            fields : ['name', 'value'],
            data   : data
        })            
    });
};
```

Then in your list of **items** call it like this:

```
createCombo('Reason for Contact', 'reason', ['data correction', 'new contact', 'missing information'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Extend reusable components by creating xtypes. http://www.sencha.com/learn/Manual:Component:Extending_Ext_Components